# Jetpack Compose - Animate custom toggle / segmented-control

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a custom toggle / segmented control in Compose, and it works fine.  However, I would ideally like it to animate when you tap either option.  So the selected/highlighted item would shift from the left to the right and vice versa, based on a given millisecond time for the animation.  I am not sure where to begin on doing this based on my setup.  I've copied the working code below.  Is this possible, or would it require a lot of re-work?  And if the sliding left and right animation is complex, I am open to really any sort of animation to make the transition a bit smoother looking.

```
@Composable
fun SegmentedControl(
    textButton1: String,
    textButton2: String,
    onClickListenerButton1: () -> Unit,
    onClickListenerButton2: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
val states = listOf(
    textButton1,
    textButton2,
)
var selectedOption by remember {
    mutableStateOf(states[0])
}
val onSelectionChange = { text: String ->
    selectedOption = text
}

val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Surface(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
    modifier = modifier
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        states.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
            val isSelected = text == selectedOption

            val customModifier = if (isSelected) {
                Modifier
                    .shadow(
                        elevation = 16.dp,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
                        clip = true
                    )
                    .background(Color.Green)
            } else {
                Modifier
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                        indication = null
                    ) {
                        onSelectionChange(text)
                        if (index == 0) {
                            onClickListenerButton1()
                        } else {
                            onClickListenerButton2()
                        }
                    }
                    .then(customModifier)
                    .padding(
                        vertical = 14.dp
                    )
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    color = if (isSelected) Color.Black else Color.DarkGray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```